# Programatically add constraints to a scrollview in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm seeing strange behaviour for a scrollview that I'm trying to horizontally centre on the device.

I've a scrollview, set up in viewDidLoad()

```
scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```

and I've added a containerView for my content. I changed the background color here to try to be able to see what is going on

```
containerView = UIView()
containerView.backgroundColor = .black
scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

To test this, I decided to set up a leading constant for the containerView (I'll centre it later).

```
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
```

The view does seem to move 50 to the right. However
1) I lose the background color of containerView
2) containerView no longer seems to react to gestures

I thought I'd be smarter, and add the constraint to the scrollView instead - I keep the color and the gestures but it doesn't shift to the right.

Comment: You also can use [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography), to write constrains more easily and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

constraints between scrollView and view controller view

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
```

constraints between scrollView and containerView

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
    ])
```

Hope is helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have the almost the same issue before with scrollView. Try landing the container using only CGRect like you did with the contentSize. In this case, translatesAutoresizingMaskConstraint should be true.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by landing the container

Comment: I mean not use constraint in your containerView view. If you want use constraint, use constraint in your scrollView Too.  In my case, I did without constraint.